# Send string array from java client to NodeJs server

Tags: java, android, arrays, node.js, socketstream

I'm developing an Android app that will send a string array to an external NodeJs server running on the Raspberry Pi.

I'm currently handling the sending side of the app using an AsyncTask, with a socket layer setup inside targeted at the NodeJs server. The server is successfully receiving calls from the app using net and socket modules, however I'm struggling to pass actual data.

At the moment I'm using OutputStream to send data.

```
OutputStream socketStream = socket.getOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socketStream);
objectOutput.writeObject(new String[] {"Test", "Test2", "Test3"});


Log.i("Array Object", objectOutput.toString());

objectOutput.close();
socketStream.close();
```

Is this the correct method of writing a string array to send to a NodeJs server?

Also what would the code contain on the NodeJs server in order to read this written data once it has been received?

**Update**

The NodeJs server is based off this tutorial http://helloraspberrypi.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/create-tcp-server-using-nodejs-with-net.html

Where the function callback_server_connection is called in the net.createServer(callback_server_connection); function.

```
function callback_server_connection(socket){
    var remoteAddress = socket.remoteAddress;
    var remotePort = socket.remotePort;
    socket.setNoDelay(true);
    console.log("connected: ", remoteAddress, " : ", remotePort);

    var msg = 'Hello ' + remoteAddress + ' : ' +  remotePort + '\r\n'
        + "You are #" + count + '\r\n';
    count++;

    socket.end(msg);

    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });

    socket.on('end', function () {
        console.log("ended: ", remoteAddress, " : ", remotePort);
    });
  }
```

Comment: If these are your first tiries then why start with a string array? Just start with one string first and see what the server receives.

Comment: If I'm honest, I'm very new to this, so am unsure as to how send/receive information

Comment: That i understand. That's why I suggested you to start with sending one String first.

Comment: This is the code to send one string: `String text = "my first message comes here.";
   OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
   os.write((text + "\n").getBytes());`.

Comment: Ok thanks for this - the server side code is successfully displaying this string. Is it possible to send Key arrays with this output stream or can it only be done via strings?

Comment: Probably. Don't know. But why would you? Why not send a line for every array item? Just put that code in a loop. `String myStrings[] = new String[] {"Test", "Test2", "Test3"};` then loop with:  `os.write((myStrings[nr] + "\n").getBytes()); `

Comment: `Key arrays`. Please explain what you have in mind.

Comment: I'd like to send variable notification information to the server. So for example ('packageName'=>varPackage, 'title'=>varTitle, 'info'=>varInfo)

Comment: Well just send as strings "packageName=org.example.com" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try to serialize your data with json